# Hover and custom attribute isn't working on IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, hover

Hover and custom attribute isn't working for me at all on IE8, not even in compatibility mode. I have the following code([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/JCQWy/)) which is working in mozilla, opera, safari, and chrome, but not IE8.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="aniRunmated" bxTab="home_pane">Home</li>
    <li class="animated" bxTab="news_pane">News</li>
    <li class="animated" bxTab="project_pane">Project Outline</li>
    <li class="animated" bxTab="gallery_pane">Gallery</li>
    <li class="animated" bxTab="downloads_pane">Downloads</li>
    <li class="animated" bxTab="links_pane">Links</li>
</ul>

    <div id="home_pane" class="tabbed">Home</div>
    <div id="news_pane" class="tabbed">News</div>
    <div id="project_pane" class="tabbed">Project</div>
    <div id="gallery_pane" class="tabbed">Gallery</div>
    <div id="downloads_pane" class="tabbed">Downloads</div>
    <div id="links_pane" class="tabbed">Links</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('li.animated').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },function(){;
        $(this).removeClass('active');
});

$('[bxTab]').click(function(){
        $('.tabbed').css('display','none');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('bxTab')).css('display','block');
});
```

I've tried usign different versions of jquery, 1.3.2 and 1.4.2 and nothing seems to work

Comment: The current version of jQuery is `1.6.4`, why are you trying to accomplish this with `1.3.2` or `1.4.2`? Besides, why not store the id of the element in a data attribute `data-bxtab="home_pane"`, then access it with `$(this).data('bxtab')`?

Comment: Works for me in IE8. Both hover and custom attributes seem to work ok.

Comment: @Shef, at least hover is not working for me.

Comment: @Stuiterbal, plz give some details of your envirenment?

Comment: @Sameera Of course, it won't work. What's this `},function(){;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li.animated').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
});

$('[bxTab]').click(function(){
        $('.tabbed').css('display','none');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('bxTab')).css('display','block');
});
```

There was additional semicolen remved. Thanks for the tip.